# Is this possible to create a manual review ban longer than a single month?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, review-suspension

As far as I know, site moderators can give at most a month long review ban manually via their tools.

Is this possible somehow to give a longer review ban?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: "*I think, sometimes it could be needed to give a longer time*" You must surely have an *exact* example? Otherwise is this just a "maybe we'll need it one day" question?

Comment: @peterh using different wording, you can make this a neutral support question e.g. simple "Is it possible to have a review ban longer than a month?" without throwing CM's and personal opinions into this (which I believe is why you get so many downvotes). I considered editing myself, but that would radically change this question so letting you decide.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No problem, I intended to make exactly a neutral support question. Do it - and thank you very much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is it *theoretically* possible? Sure. It's just a date field in a database table, we could set it to December 31, 9999 if there was a need for that.

So far, there hasn't been a pressing need for that. I would strongly encourage you to avoid creating one.

Comment: Right - in most cases, it would be more expedient to just suspend the poor reviewer entirely.

Comment: Can a moderator "extend" existing review ban while it's still active? That would pretty much give the OP what he's asking for, no?

Comment: it sounds like you have a [Y9999 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)

Comment: As implied, the end-date is stored - so it could be kept perpetually 30 days out. @Sha